# Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,3]  )
y_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

print(X_p)

x = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
y = [[1],[2]]

weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]))



model = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X_p,weight)+1)

error = tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(model))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(error)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for x in range(100):
        sess.run(optimizer, {X_p: x, y_p:y})
```

X_p is of shape [None,3], x is shape [2,3], y_p = [None,1], y = [2,1]

I don't really understand why placeholder is stopping numpy array to fetch the data.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run a session using my own `optimizer` variable it works fine. Maybe you could provide a more complete example that others could actually run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Mark_M Ok, did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are overwriting your `x` variable by also using `x` as a loop variable. So when you try to pass`x` into the feed dict you are passing the loop variable rather than your tensor. Try changing you loop variable to something else such as:

```
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(optimizer, {X_p: x, y_p:y})
```

Comment: Lol, yeah can't believe how i didn't notice that. Thanks:)